# How to recursively clone a particular tag in git

Tags: git, github

How to do a recursive clone of a particular tag in git? I know the following list of commands will do it. But is there a shorter way?

```
$ git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
$ cd repo
$ git checkout tags/<tag-name> 
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Recursive clone a tag in one line:

```
git clone --recursive --branch <tag-name> https://github.com/user/repo.git
```